# Two pots controlling 2 servos -- odd behavior

Tags: arduino-nano, servo, potentiometer

I'm trying to control 2 servos with 2 pots. I thought I could just amend the tutorial code by adding in the extra pot on a1 and extra servo on d8 (am using a Nano).

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo
Servo myservo_2;

int potpin = 0;  // analog pin used to connect the potentiometer
int potpin_2 = 1;
int val;    // variable to read the value from the analog pin
int val_2;

void setup() {
  myservo.attach(9);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
  myservo_2.attach(8);
}

void loop() {
  val = analogRead(potpin);            // reads the value of the potentiometer (value between 0 and 1023)
  val_2 = analogRead(potpin_2);
  val = map(val, 0, 1023, 0, 180);     // scale it to use it with the servo (value between 0 and 180)
  val_2 = map(val_2, 0, 1023, 0, 180);
  myservo.write(val);                  // sets the servo position according to the scaled value
  myservo_2.write(val_2);
  delay(15);                           // waits for the servo to get there
}
```

...but the servos only respond to one of the pots (on a0) & both move to the same position regardless of what value is on a1.

Am I missing something really obvious? Why is the value on a1 ignored & why is the value mapped from a0 sent to both d8 & d9?

I have swapped out the pot on a1 just in case it was faulty but I get the same behavior.

EDIT: Added schematic

[image: Dual servo schematic]

EDIT: I swapped out the Nano for another Nano but that failed to upload the sketch. So I put the original back in & now evrything is working fine!

Darn'd if I can get my head around it, possibly a bad connection with the bread board?

Anyway all working now thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: How are your potentiometers connected?

Comment: between the + & - rails with the sliders connected to a0 & a1. Works fine for the unaltered single servo code from the tutorial

Comment: added schematic for clarity

Comment: Use `A0` and `A1` in your code for the analog pins instead of `0` and `1`.

Comment: Using A0 & A1 has made no difference to the behavior

Comment: That the reading from a0 and send it to both servos but reverse one of them (180-value).

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea whats wrong with your system, but this might help you diagnose it.

```
#include <Servo.h>

static const size_t MaxServos = 2;              // The number of pots and servos attached
const int servoPins[MaxServos] = {9, 8};        // The pins that the servos are controlled through
const int potpins[MaxServos] = {A0, A1};        // analog pin used to connect the potentiometer
Servo myservo[MaxServos];                       // create servo object to control a servo

void setup ()
{
    for (size_t index = 0; index < MaxServos; ++index)
    {
        myservo[index].attach (servoPins[index]);
    }
}

void loop ()
{
    for (size_t index = 0; index < MaxServos; ++index)
    {
        readAndSet (potpins[index], myservo[index]);
    }
    delay (15);                           // waits for the servo to get there - might want to multiply a value by the number of degrees turned to give a better value.
}

// \brief   Read the specified analog pin and set the server proportionally
// \param   The analog pin that the pot is connected to.
// \param   The servo that will be moved
void readAndSet (const int& pin, Servo& servo)
{
    const int value = analogRead (pin);            // reads the value of the potentiometer (value between 0 and 1023)
    const int mappedValue = map (value, 0, 1023, 0, 180);     // scale it to use it with the servo (value between 0 and 180)
    servo.write (mappedValue);                  // sets the servo position according to the scaled value
}
```

I have refactored your code to eliminate the duplication.  This means you will get more test coverage and you should find the bug quicker.  You could add a `Serial print` statement to the `readAndSet` function to ensure that you are passing and calculating the right values, but I suspect you are.

There appears to be nothing wrong with the code, so is it possible that there is some hardware limitation?  Is there a short between the lines that causes the pot on A1 to be bypassed?

Comment: thanks, what is `size_t`? I edited my question, once I swapped out then replaced the orignal Nano the system works as expected.

Comment: its an `unsigned int`.  You only need to count from 0 to +0xffff so don't bother using an int.